# Django How to Select One Foriegn Key Among Multiple Foriegn Keys

Tags: django, database

I have two models know i created a third one in which i want to link any one between these two forign keys but not both of them and i want to show both of them while linking then we choose one of them

```
author = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='author',on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, blank=False) 
question = models.ForeignKey(Questions, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments') 
answer = models.ForeignKey(Answers, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='answers')
```

know i want to choose one b/w question and answers . Either user put comments on question or answers one at a time
like we comment on stack overflow questions and answers
should i create seperate models for both question comment and answers comment or one can handle both of them

Comment: Can you share your models and other relevant files?

Comment: A comment section for question and answers models but user may put comment on question or answer one at a time

Comment: author = models.ForeignKey(
        User, related_name='author', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, blank=False)
    question = models.ForeignKey(
        Questions, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    answer = models.ForeignKey(
        Answers, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='answers')

Comment: Hi zain, click the edit button under your post and please add your required code snippets